# Text on JTextField doesn't appear until frame resize

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, grid-layout

When I click on a button a property frame appears. Each row has these 3 fields : JLabel name, JTextField value, JSlider slider. My problem is that when the frame shows, it displays the values correctly, but the text in the JTextField fails to appear until I resize the frame for a bit. I use GridLayout for the JPanel containing the components
Any suggestions on what I might do?

```
frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setTitle("Properties of " + nume);

    ok = new JButton("OK");
    no = new JButton("Cancel");

    modified = true;
```

// <"Labels, sliders ,text fields">

// <"add the components on the panel">

```
    buttonsPanel.add(ok);
    buttonsPanel.add(no);

    JSplitPane framePanel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, jsp, buttonsPanel);
    framePanel.setDividerLocation(0.9);
    framePanel.setDividerSize(0);
    framePanel.setResizeWeight(1);

    frame.add(framePanel);
```

Here is what my frame shows the 1st time:
[image]

And then after I resize it the values appear:
[image]

Comment: something is wrong with your code - please show a SSCCE

Answer (score -1):

The call doLayout() on the parent control of the JTextField

Comment: the DoLayout is of no use to me :(

Comment: I solved it with GridBagLayout, although it was my last option :)

Comment: I solved it with GridBagLayout, although it was my last option. It seems that GridLayout made the 3 columns wider than the frame's width. Using GridBag, the columns were contained within the frame, so the values in the textfields appear normally at frame startup.